# how to edit the tooltip for a spider chart in highcharts

Tags: jquery, django, charts, highcharts

Hi – I have a spider chart that I’ve built via Highcharts in a Django application. The spider chart has 2 data series in it, each with 3 data points that correspond to category A, B and C. Currently when I tooltip over the chart (e.g. on category A), the tooltip shows category A values for for both series 1 and series 2. 
The tooltip property of the chart currently is set as:

```
 tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}"> {series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.#f}</b><br/>',
        valueDecimals: 1,
    },
```

What I’d like to also show when a user tooltips on any of the 3 categories, in addition to the above, is a ratio of the data point for series 1 and 2 for the category formatted as a percentage.

For example (lets assume):

Series 1 values correspond to category A, B, C = 2, 4, 6

Series 2 values that correspond to category A, B, C = 3, 5, 7

When a user tooltips over category A on the spider chart, I’m trying to show, both the raw values for (2 and 3) and then the ratio of  the two (3/2 -1 )= 50%

My full chart code is listed below. really appreciate any help

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(function () {
$('#spider_container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'line'

    },
    title: {
        text: 'Ratings for {{instance.first_name}}',
        x: -80
    },
    pane: {
        size: '80%'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                align: 'left',
                enabled: true,
                allowOverlap: false  
            }
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Enjoyed working with them (1-5)', 'Learned from them (1-5)', 'Had domain competency (1-5)'],
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        lineWidth: 0
    },
    yAxis: {
        gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}"> {series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.#f}</b><br/>',
        valueDecimals: 1,
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 70,
        layout: 'vertical'
    },
    series: [{
        name: '{{instance}}',
        data: [{{ques1_employee_avg|floatformat}}, {{ques2_employee_avg|floatformat}}, 
        {{ques3_employee_avg|floatformat}}],
        pointPlacement: 'on',
        color: '#000080'
    }, {
        name: 'Overall Avg.',
        data: [{{ques1_overall_avg|floatformat}}, {{ques2_overall_avg|floatformat}}, 
        {{ques3_overall_avg|floatformat}}],
        pointPlacement: 'on',
        color: '#B0C4DE'
    }]
});
});
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I think that you can use tooltip formatter for making your chart with additional information. Here you can find an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/288zfqmx/1/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!